# Yellow artifacts when baking normals

Tags: uv, normals, baking, artifacts

I've been searching and trying a few things for the last couple of hours and I can't figure out why there are yellow spots showing up on the normals when I bake them. Originally the wings had the same issue and the normals had to be flipped, but that doesn't seem to be working for the rest. Any ideas would be appreciated. [image: The problem]

Comment: Please upvote if I answered your question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Baking normals can be tricky. If the normal of the lowpoly object is roughly the same as the highpoly object, the bake will be that bluish-cyan-pink that we like. However, if the normals points in opposite direction, the bake will be the inversion of those colors, as the yellow-brown-red.

Then why does the normals point in opposite direction? That could happen if the highpoly object intersects itself. The baking process have difficulty to find the correct face, with the correct normal.

Here are some images with a good and bad case:

[image: good case]

[image: bad case]

In the second case the highpoly mesh intersects with itself. The lowpoly object can't be projected on the highpoly with a good result.

Comment: Based off what you said and the images, I realized that the objects were overlapping and blocking off the baking process. So I created 5 normals with all the objects baked separately and combined them in photoshop. Worked like a charm, thanks! It did feel like a outdated work around though. Is this common practice or is there a technique out there I'm missing for baking character with overlapping meshes, which is very common.

Comment: You can get better control with a cage. I only know the theory behind it though.