# Normal Baking Showing Yellow

Tags: uv, shaders, texture-baking, normals

I have a lightsaber hilt that I'm trying to bake. I made a low poly mesh first, then I added a subdivision surface modifier to my low poly mesh to make a high poly version. Because I added the subdivision surface modifier to the high poly one, it is smaller (generally) than my low-poly one. Both of the models are shaded smooth. Whenever I go to bake the normals, there are always yellow spots. Just as a note, most of the yellow pieces are cylindrical.

Please help me get rid of the yellow spots. Thank you :)

Here is what I'm getting so far:

Extrusion: .01m. Cage: Active. Margin: 1px.
[image]

Extrusion: 1m. Cage: Active. Margin: 1px.
[image]

Extrusion: 1m. Cage: Active. Margin: 16px.
[image]

Ray Distance: 1m. Cage: Disabled. Margin: 16px.
[image]

Ray Distance: .01m. Cage: Disabled. Margin: 16px.
[image]

Ray Distance: .01m. Cage: Disabled. Margin: 1px.
[image]

Edit: I have gone into edit mode, selected everything and recalculated the normals. It eliminated the worst of the yellow, but there are still a few lines hanging around. [image]

Comment: Hello :). I'm no expert, but this thread could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/63525/78972

Comment: Is it not baking because the meshes are too different?

Comment: You will probably need to upload the blend file to get a good answer. Make sure that normals is pointing in the correct way on both low and highpoly.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to add a file, do I do it through an external site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just went and baked the normal map with xNormal. Then, I imported it, created a new material and texture and hooked it up. It is a good quality, but I can tell it is jagged in some areas.[image]

So, this is more of a workaround rather than a fix, but it's the solution that I'm probably going to be using from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, the problem was that the normals were facing the wrong way. I corrected the normals and baked as usual. Worked.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)